# Is sigmoid function distributive

Tags: functions

Sigmoid function is defined as $\frac{1}{1+e^{-(x+y)}}$.

Is there a property for sigmoid such that

$\frac{1}{1+e^{-(x+y)}}=$ sigmoid$(x)$ {some operation} sigmoid$(y)$ ?

Edit:

According to [this](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=JTeqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=is%20sigmoid%20function%20distributive&source=bl&ots=bPQXm6QMC2&sig=fhIPkna-Zw7lPND5FAu41YiXOlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqzvWsmebeAhUEo48KHfCuCSsQ6AEwFHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20sigmoid%20function%20distributive&f=false) link it is not. However, is there any way that I can approximate them such that they are almost equal to the original one.

Edit 2:
If I use taylor series, how can I make it distributive?